# Automatically break line if it spans over x centimetres

Tags: line-breaking

I am using [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) to insert latex text and equations to PowerPoint presentation.

This plug-in uses a default template to generate latex images (it compiles it to pdf then to image).

Here's an example of an output:
[image]

And here's the input that produces the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{153,255,255}
\color{mywhite}

\begin{document}


    \begin{itemize}
        \item
        A compression technique used to reduce the bits needed\\
        to encode symbols (e.g. letters).
        \item
        Based on the frequency of occurrence of a symbol in the data.
        \item
        Huffman code is optimal.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item To use our definitions and notations, given a text\\
            containing $n$ different letters where $w_i$ is the frequency\\
            of the $i$’th letter, Huffman Algorithm constructs\\
            an Extended Binary Tree while minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n w_il_i$. 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Notice how I must break the lines manually by adding `\\` wherever I find fit. This is really annoying and time consuming. I would love to make it automatically somehow.

In other words, what I'm asking is:
I want the line to automatically break whenever adding a word to it makes it span over more than x centimetres. Is that possible?

Comment: Set the textwidth accordingly using package `geometry`or put the stuff inside a `parbox`.

Comment: Would you mind writing that as an answer and add an example? I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: Sorry, but presentations *require* manual breaking. Each slide should be looked at in order to find the best page breaks and no automated system will be able to do that: it's the same as breaking equations across lines, where the right place where to split depends on subtle semantic aspects.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the tip. Actually, that's exactly what I'm doing: some of the slides have lines that I manually broke, but most of them are just text and it is easier that way. 
That's why I prefer having automatic line breaking as a default, and whatever needs fine tuning is handled manually.

Comment: @so.very.tired `\raggedright` is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the `textwidth` to have a certain value using package `geometry`. Alternatively, a parbox could be used, but they cannot be broken over pages. Use `\raggedright` to get non-justified text.

[image: soverytiredNarrowTextwidth]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mywhite}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{153,255,255}
%\color{mywhite}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=10cm}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
    \item
        A compression technique used to reduce the bits needed
        to encode symbols (e.g. letters).
    \item
        Based on the frequency of occurrence of a symbol in the data.
    \item
        Huffman code is optimal.
        \begin{itemize}
            \item To use our definitions and notations, given a text
                containing $n$ different letters where $w_i$ is the frequency
                of the $i$’th letter, Huffman Algorithm constructs
                an Extended Binary Tree while minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n w_il_i$. 
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```